# how to update table with group by and functions?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to update some columns in Postgresql but I have realized there are some GROUP BY and having conditions and sum fuction. 
the select statement:

```
SELECT mp.name , mbl.product_id, "produced",sum(round(mbl.product_qty*smp.product_uom_qty/mb.product_qty,3)) "theo" ,sum(round(smc.product_uom_qty,3)) "real"
FROM stock_move smp LEFT JOIN mrp_production mp ON (mp.id=smp.production_id and smp.state in('done','cancel') ) 
LEFT JOIN stock_move smc on  mp.id=smc.raw_material_production_id 
LEFT JOIN mrp_bom mb ON mb.id=mp.bom_id LEFT JOIN mrp_bom_line mbl ON mbl.bom_id=mb.id
WHERE smc.product_id=mbl.product_id  and mp.state='done'
GROUP BY mp.name,mbl.product_id  having sum(round(mbl.product_qty*smp.product_uom_qty/mb.product_qty,3))!=sum(round(smc.product_uom_qty,3))
```

I would like to update the

```
stock_move.product_uom_qty=sum(mbl.product_qty*smp.product_uom_qty/mb.product_qty)
```

I tried this:

```
UPDATE stock_move sm SET product_uom_qty=sum(mbl.product_qty*smp.product_uom_qty/mb.product_qty )
FROM stock_move smp  LEFT JOIN mrp_production mp ON (mp.id=smp.production_id and smp.state in('done','cancel') ) 
LEFT JOIN mrp_bom mb ON mb.id=mp.bom_id LEFT JOIN mrp_bom_line mbl ON mbl.bom_id=mb.id  LEFT JOIN stock_move smc ON  mp.id=smc.raw_material_production_id  
GROUP BY mp.name,mbl.product_id 
HAVING SUM(round(mbl.product_qty*smp.product_uom_qty/mb.product_qty,3))!=SUM(round(smc.product_uom_qty,3)))
WHERE sm.product_id=smc.product_id
```

I got:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group"
LINE 4: group by mp.name,mbl.product_id
```

Comment: .. and when you tried this, what happened? Show your table definitions please, as well as sample data and expected results.

Comment: `FROM stock_move smp` You don't need stock_move in the FROM list, it is already the target for the update And: you have an extra `)` parenthesis, AND: your where clause is at the wrong place. Plus: the final `WHERE sm.product_id=smc.product_id` turns all LEFT JOINS into normal joins.

Comment: If you're going to `UPDATE ... FROM` with grouping and aggregation etc, you'll have to do it over a subquery-in-FROM.

Comment: @wildplasser the smp is required

Comment: Well, in that case: put it into a `(subquery)` , as @CraigRinger suggested.

Comment: Yes: first get the first `SELECT` query working (there is a `,` too much). Then use that in a `UPDATE xx SET ... FROM( complete_subquery) yy WHERE xx.kk = yy.kk;`  And: please add some whitespace/linebreaks;  the query in the current form is unreadable, IMHO.

Comment: @wildplasser ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "mbl"

Comment: any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the `WITH AS` as the folowing query

```
WITH tabpro AS (
SELECT smc.id,mp.name AS name, mbl.product_id ,sum(smp.product_uom_qty) "produced",sum(round(mbl.product_qty*smp.product_uom_qty/mb.product_qty,3)) AS realqty ,sum(round(smc.product_uom_qty,3))  "REAl" --,mbl.product_uom,smc.product_uom
FROM stock_move smp LEFT JOIN mrp_production mp ON (mp.id=smp.production_id AND smp.state in('done','cancel') ) LEFT JOIN stock_move smc ON  mp.id=smc.raw_material_production_id  
LEFT JOIN mrp_bom mb ON mb.id=mp.bom_id LEFT JOIN mrp_bom_line mbl ON mbl.bom_id=mb.id  
WHERE  smc.product_id=mbl.product_id  AND mp.state='done' --and mp.name like '%207'
GROUP BY smc.id, mp.name,mbl.product_id 
HAVING sum(round(mbl.product_qty*smp.product_uom_qty/mb.product_qty,3))!=sum(round(smc.product_uom_qty,3))
) 
UPDATE stock_move sm SET product_uom_qty=tabpro.realqty FROM tabpro
WHERE sm.product_id=tabpro.product_id AND sm.name=tabpro.name AND sm.id=tabpro.id;
```